# Right Rotation Binary Search Tree Java

Tags: java, rotation, binary-search

I am brushing up on some simple data structures and I am having trouble making the rotations in my BST work properly.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

    private static class Node {
        Node parent; //null for root node
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int data;

        //constructor for node
        Node(int newData) {
            left = null;
            right = null;
            parent = null;
            data = newData;
        }
    }
    private Node root; //root null in empty 


    //search methods
    public boolean search(int data) {
        return search(root,data); //true if exists
    }

    private boolean search(Node n, int data) {
        if(n == null) 
            return false; //node doesn't exist
        if(data == n.data) //found
            return true;
        else if(data < n.data) //data on left if exists
            return search(n.left, data);
        else //data on right if it exists
            return search(n.right,data);
    }

    public Node findNode(int data) {
        return findNode(root,data);
    }
    private Node findNode(Node n, int data) {
        if(n == null)
            return n; //nothing exists here
        else if (data < n.data) //data should be on left if it exists
            return findNode(n.left,data);
        else if(data > n.data) //data should be on right if it exists
            return findNode(n.right,data);
        else
            return n; //found it
    }

    //recursive insertion
    public void insertNode(int data) {
        root = insertNode(root,null,data);
    }

    private Node insertNode(Node n, Node parentNode, int data) {
        if(n == null) {
            n = new Node(data); //if node doesn't exist add it here
            n.parent = parentNode;
        }
        else {
            if(data <= n.data) {
                n.left = insertNode(n.left,n,data);
            } else {
                n.right = insertNode(n.right,n,data);
            }
        }
        return n; //return self at end (will go back to root)
    }

    //rotations
    public void rotateLeft(Node n) {
        Node y = n.right;

        n.right = y.left;  //y's left subtree into n's right subtree
        if(y.left != null) 
            y.left.parent = n;

        y.parent = n.parent; 

        //link n's parent to y
        if(n.parent == null) //check to see if we are at root
            root = y;
        else if(n == n.parent.left) //n on left of parent
            n.parent.left = y;
        else                       //n on right of parent
            n.parent.right = y;

        y.left = n; 
        n.parent = y;  //n on y's left 
    }
    public void rotateRight(Node n) {
        Node y = n.left;

        n.left = y.right;
        if(y.right != null)
            y.right.parent = n;

        y.parent = n.parent;
        if(n.parent == null)
            root = y;
        else if(n == n.parent.right)
            n.parent.right = y;
        else
            n.parent.left = y;

        y.right = n;
        n.parent = y;

    }

    //Printing
    public void printPreorder() {
        printPreorder(root);
    }
    private void printPreorder(Node n) {
        if(n == null) //nothing here
            return;
        System.out.print(n.data + " "); //print node data here
        printPreorder(n.left);
        printPreorder(n.right);
    }

    public void printInorder() {
        printInorder(root);
    }

    private void printInorder(Node n) {
        if(n == null) //nothing here
            return;
        printInorder(n.left);
        System.out.print(n.data + " "); //print data here (in order)
        printInorder(n.right);
    }

    public void printPostorder() {
        printPostorder(root);
    }

    private void printPostorder(Node n) {
        if(n == null)
            return; //nothing here
        printPostorder(n.left);
        printPostorder(n.right);
        //node is here so print data
        System.out.print(n.data + " ");
    }


}
```

quick messy main

```
public class MainBST {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BinarySearchTree BST = new BinarySearchTree();
        //test run
        BST.insertNode(8);
        BST.insertNode(7);
        BST.insertNode(5);
        BST.insertNode(6);
        BST.insertNode(3);
        BST.insertNode(4);

        System.out.print("Before rotation: \nPre-order: ");
        BST.printPreorder();
        System.out.print("\nIn-order: ");
        BST.printInorder();
        System.out.print("\nPost-order: ");
        BST.printPostorder();

        if(BST.search(5)) 
            BST.rotateRight(BST.findNode(5));

        System.out.print("\n\nAfter rotation: \nPre-order: ");
        BST.printPreorder();
        System.out.print("\nIn-order: ");
        BST.printInorder();
        System.out.print("\nPost-order: ");
        BST.printPostorder();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Before rotation: 
Pre-order: 8 7 5 3 4 6 
In-order: 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Post-order: 4 3 6 5 7 8 

After rotation: 
Pre-order: 8 7 3 5 4 6 
In-order: 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Post-order: 4 6 5 3 7 8
```

However this is the expected output after rotation (I have the right output for the tree before rotation):

```
Pre-order: 8 5 3 4 7 6
In-order: 3 4 5 6 7 8
Post-order: 4 3 6 7 5 8
```

It is clear there is some problem. Maybe it has to do with my wonky findNode() or the node structure? Or possibly even the rotation method has a problem. Can anyone help me out?